# On Symfony 2, losing session with iframe on IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, session, iframe, symfony

I'm making a facebook application with Symfony 2. Many people know that IE loses sessions when including an iframe !

This problem can be solved thanks to header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

So my problem is to send header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); on Symfony 2.

I tried this in my action:

```
$response = new Response($content);     
$response->headers->set('P3P:CP', 'CAO PSA OUR');
return array($response);
```

Without success, sessions are lost !!!

Have an idea to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find my solution !

Just replace this:

```
$response->headers->set('P3P:CP', 'CAO PSA OUR');
```

By:

```
 $response->headers->set('P3P', 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Or better, like Wojciech Bańcer says:

```
$response->headers->set('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

In fact, you must pass in first parameter all words before :, and the rest in second one !

Answer (score 3):

IE can loose session/cookie for various reasons.

The most common one, you named - missing P3P header (you should check with some Firebug tool, to make sure you are sending it).

The second reason is an underscore in domain name (for example my_app.something.com). This is because underscore in name is against RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt . If I remember correctly (I hit similar bug 2 years ago), it may also be the case when your symfony cookie name have an underscore.

The third most common reason I've heard of was related to the time, but I never experienced this myself. You may read about it in this article: http://genotrance.wordpress.com/2006/11/23/session-cookies-rejected-by-internet-explorer/