# On Symfony 2, losing session with iframe on IE, in all actions

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, session, iframe, symfony

I've exactly the same problem:
[On Symfony 2, losing session with iframe on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260482/on-symfony-2-losing-session-with-iframe-on-ie)

```
$response->headers->set('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

But i've a lot of action and i use automatic template:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="_welcome")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    ....  
    return array(...);
}
```

So is it possible to define header in all actions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event listener for the response.

Here you find an example for this using the Acme Bundle that ships with Symfony2:

http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-create-a-response-filter-and-set-extra-response-headers/

Basically you would adapt this example and write:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }
}
```